# Access model that fired event inside callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In the following example how would I access the model who triggered the "change:guid" event in the callback function?

```
Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        db: 'not specified',
        guid: 'not specified'
    },

    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.on("change:guid", function (e) {
            alert(" guid changed!!!!!");
            //access model here
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"e" should be the model. According to the documentation the following parameters can be used in the callback:
"change:[attribute]" (model, value, options)

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Example:

```
Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        db: 'not specified',
        guid: 'not specified'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.on("change:guid", function (model, value, options) {            
            console.log(model);
        })
        this.set('guid', 123);
    }
});
var entry = new Entry()
```

If you take a look at the console, there will be the model.
Try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7hXS/

Comment: Can you give an example?  I was trying to solve this problem myself and saw someone mention that e.target should be the model but it is not.

Comment: I've added an example and a jsfiddle to try it.